# Azure IoT cloud-to-device messaging via Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm currently building an API in Rails to control devices registered with an Azure IoT Hub.

Now, in the Azure documentation, I only see Python/Node/.Net guides to control the end devices.

I require Rails for certain libraries, and hence used it to build my API. But now I've hit this road block.

Is there no way I can send cloud-to-device messages? I don't see any official Rails support. I only require c2d messaging.

Edit : The only other way I can think of with my limited knowledge is to deploy a small Python/Flask app on the same server and have my Rails code make HTTP requests to it. Is this a bad approach?

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend to use the Azure HttpTrigger Function for your solutions as an API integrator/mediator.